[GSI_LOGGER]: Google OneTap Migrate to FedCM with "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'origin')"
I have successfully implemented Google OneTap login via HTML API for my website. I'm currently             testing opt-in to FebCM and have set ‘data-use_fedcm_for_prompt="true"’ as per the documentation.
HTML api configuration is as follows: <div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="my_client_id" data-context="use" data-ux_mode="popup" data-auto_select="false" data-itp_support="false" data-use_fedcm_for_prompt="true" data-callback="handleGoogleCredential"\>

Please see the picture for console error.

How to fix this error?
